# Поломался JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js

Добрый день! Ситуация такая: обрабатываю форму и на ее основании создаю Объект. Перед отправкой AJAX- стрингую его `JSON.stringify(data)`. Все норм. На сервере, полученный запрос прогоняю через связку модулей, не совершая над ним никаких действий (тестирую коллбэки). И возвращаю назад.

По приходу ответа, парсю его: `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`, вроде бы все норм. Ошибок никаких не выдает. Однако в консоль выводится строка. Мой объект, только в виде строки.

В чем может быть причина такого поведения?

вывод консоли:

```
{"delivery":{"adresat":{"lastName":"Иванов","firstName":"Дмитрий","secondName":"Петрович","inn":"111111111","tel":"(044)1234567","email":"jhfejfek@gmail.com"},"client":{"lastName":"Сидорода","firstName":"Мария","secondName":"Николаевна","inn":"2222222222","tel":"(097)1234567","email":"jhsjdj@gmail.com"},"post":{"cod":{"office":"39931ae9-e1c2-11e3-8c4a-0050568002cf","obl":"dcaae3a1-4b33-11e4-ab6d-005056801329","raion":"e4aa4da4-4b33-11e4-ab6d-005056801329","city":"e71815c4-4b33-11e4-ab6d-005056801329"},"text":{"office":"Отделение №1: ул. 1 Мая, 2а","obl":"Харьковская область","raion":"Золочевский р-н","city":"Золочев"}}},"cart":[16,17]}
```

Comment: например в том, что сервер сериализует строку

Comment: @Grundy, доброго времени суток. А можно немного подробнее, а то я не понимаю(

Comment: У тебя есть на сервере строка, и перед отправкой ты ее еще раз сериализуешь, поэтому на клиенте получаешь сериализованную строку

Comment: @Grundy, так и есть. Только делал я это еще до отправки на сервер. Жесть) Спасибо за помощь.